# Can't set the same color for background and border in UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift

I am trying to customize my segmented control with Swift, but I have run into a problem. I set the same color (e.g. UIColor.red) for border and background, but they look different. My code is:

```
segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 12
segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 2
segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
segmentedControl.layer.masksToBounds = true
segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .red
```

Maybe someone knows how can I fix it?

[image: Screen shot of my segmented control. You can notice that border and bg colors differ a bit]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `tintColor` and `selectedSegmentTintColor`:

```swift
segmentedControl.tintColor = .white
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentTintColor = .white
```